# Use the Divergence theorem to find the flux of a vector field F across a surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Title: Finding the divergence and flux of a vector field

Problem: Find the divergence of the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ and use the Divergence Theorem to find the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across the surface $\sigma$ with outward orientation, where $\sigma$ is given by the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$.

Vector field: $\mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = (5 + 3x + x^3 - 2z^2)\mathbf{i} + (2y + y^2 + 3x^3)\mathbf{j} - (1 + 2z + 3y^3)\mathbf{k}$

So far, I have calculated the divergence of the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ to be $3x^2 + 2y + 3$.

To find the flux using the Divergence Theorem, I used the formula:

$\text{flux} = \iiint_V (\operatorname{div} \mathbf{F}) ,dV$,

where V is the solid region enclosed by the surface σ.

I tried using cylindrical coordinates to evaluate the integral:

$\text{flux} = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} (3r^3\cos^2\theta + 2r^2\sin\theta + 3r) ,dz,dr,d\theta$

I am still unsure of which coordinates I should use, cylindrical or spherical.

Any suggestions or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please write your question in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I would probably use spherical coordinates, but cylindrical coordinates is fine. However, you are integrating only over the solid upper hemisphere.

Comment: I am integrating over the solid upper hemisphere , does this affect the choice of coordinates I can used for integration

Comment: Your flux integral is correct in cylindrical coordinates:

$$\int _0^{2 \pi }\int _0^R\int _0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}\left(3 r^3 \cos ^2(\theta )+2 r^2 \sin (\theta )+3 r\right)dzdrd\theta=\frac{2}{5} \pi  R^3 \left(R^2+5\right)$$

with R the radius of surface $\sigma$ $(R=2)$.